# Using TopShelf to create a simple MQ windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, topshelf

I am using Topshelf for creating a simple MQ reading service. Since the documentation available is sparse - I have run into some probably simple questions that I hope get answered here:

1) Generally - it would be very nice to get the actual servicebase instance of my service instance, since there is a bunch of methods that I would like to access. How can I do that?

2) When OnStop is called, I would like to flush the MQ and quickly process the remaining messages. However, accessing the MQ in the OnClose raises an MQ access exception - is this by design, or?

3) I have specified the OnPause and OnContinue overloads in the configurator. However - the service is not pause/continue enabled, since the AllowPauseAndContinue flag is not set. What is the best way to do that?

```
        var retVal = HostFactory.New( x =>
                        {
                            x.Service<ASForwardMessageService>( s =>
                            {
                                s.SetServiceName( s_ServiceName );
                                s.ConstructUsing( name => CreateService() );
                                s.WhenStarted( tc => tc.OnStart() );
                                s.WhenStopped( tc => tc.OnStop() );
                                s.WhenPaused( tc => tc.OnPause() );
                                s.WhenContinued( tc => tc.OnContinue() );
                            } );

                            x.RunAsLocalSystem();

                            x.DependsOnMsmq();

                            x.StartAutomatically();

                            x.SetDescription( s_Description );
                            x.SetDisplayName( s_DisplayName );
                            x.SetServiceName( s_ServiceName );
                        } );
```

By the way - is there any documentation available for the Topshelf project - would be very nice to have around.

Thanks for a great library!

Comment: What version of TopShelf are you using?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/wiki for documentation, there's also http://topshelf-project.com/ but we don't really have much in terms of docs up there. This might be a better discussion for our mailing list as well.

1. We don't expose that, though I guess it's possible we could via the new pre- and post- install events (http://legomaster.net/2011/02/announcing-topshelf-2-2/). The general idea is that anything you would need to set would be exposed via our configuration API though. What attention items do you want access to you feel that you don't have now?
2. What exception are you seeing? There isn't anything I'm aware of in the design of Topshelf which should be causing this issue.
3. `CanPauseAndContinue` isn't set; drop an issue in our issue tracker on github and I think that's something that can be resolved.

Comment: 3. "SetPausable" is currently in a pull request: https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/pull/92